# Hiding a Div without duplicating code

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a pop out menu in a div.

I'm controlling the opening and closing of the div using: `ng-click="showNavMenu = !showNavMenu"`.

However for each, link where I use this, i need to duplicate that code so that the menu actually closes, once the new view is loaded.

I'd like to avoid this code duplication - any ideas on what I can do:

```
<div class="navMenu" ng-show="showNavMenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/about" ng-click="showNavMenu = !showNavMenu">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/privacy" ng-click="showNavMenu = !showNavMenu">Privacy</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact" ng-click="showNavMenu = !showNavMenu">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use function instead
    `<li><a href="/about" ng-click="toggleMenu()">About</a></li>`

And define this function in controller

```
$scope.toggleMenu = function() {
    $scope.showNavMenu = !$scope.showNavMenu;
}
```

Comment: But I presume I'd still need to mention that in each `ng-click`

Comment: Sometimes code is more verbose than we'd like. Using tools like bootstrap make this easier instead of having to fiddle with low level code like this

Comment: Yes, but you need to define callback only once and change this behavior also only once when requirements will change.

What about to use 'ng-repeat' do render all 'li' in similar ways with defferences in href only?

Answer (score 0):

What about putting the ng-click on the parent `ul`? I'm not super well-versed in angular's event bubbling/propagation rules - there might be some tweaks you need to make to your function or to the ng-click attribute. Or it might just work.

```
function toggleMenu() {
   $scope.showNavMenu = !$scope.showNavMenu
}

-----

<ul ng-click="toggleMenu()">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with moving the navigation logic to the controller code, seems the cleanest solution to me. So your markup would look like:

```
<div class="navMenu" ng-show="showNavMenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href ng-click="navigate('about')">About</a></li>
    <li><a href ng-click="navigate('privacy')">Privacy</a></li>
    <li><a href ng-click="navigate('contact')">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And inside your controller:

```
$scope.navigate = function(path) {
  $scope.showNavMenu = false;
  window.location.href = '/' + path; //better navigate via router
}
```